# Trying to make input take all available width but not hide sibling. Works in Chrome not FF

Tags: html, css, firefox, flexbox

The goal is to have the box div aligned to the right of the ctrl and the input taking the rest of the available width.

Here's a demo. It renders as I want it to in Chrome. But in Firefox the "box" is hidden.

http://jsfiddle.net/1tgx3n2d/

```
<div id="ctrl">
    <input/>
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>

#ctrl
{
    width:130px; height:24px;
    position:relative;
    display:flex;
    overflow:hidden;

    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:solid 1px #CCC;
}
input
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background:#5ee;
    flex:1;
}
#box
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width:40px; height:22px;
    background: linear-gradient(#eee 0%, #eee 40%, #CDCDCD 100%);
}
```

How to get the same effect in FireFox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to add `min-width: 0;` to the input. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1tgx3n2d/1/)

```
input {
    min-width: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background:#5ee;
    flex:1;
}
```